# This script is too slow, any way to improve its performance?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo, translate

This script is too slow, any way to improve its performance? The word is loaded by returning this function within the page, and fetching a table in the database.

The connection is via PDO and the MySQL database

```
   function fnc_translate($texto) {
    
        include("conn.php");
    
        $lang['pt-br'] = 'PT_BR';
        $lang['en'] = 'EN';
        $lang['es'] = 'ES';    
        $lang['no'] = 'NO';
    
        if(!isset($_GET['lang']) && !isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    
            $stmt = "SELECT LANG_PT_BR FROM LANG WHERE LANG_PT_BR=:texto";
            $row_name = "LANG_PT_BR";
            $_SESSION['lang'] = 'pt-br';
    
        }elseif(!isset($_GET['lang']) && isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    
            $stmt = "SELECT LANG_".$lang[$_SESSION['lang']]." FROM LANG WHERE LANG_PT_BR=:texto";
            $row_name = "LANG_".$lang[$_SESSION['lang']];
    
        }elseif(isset($_GET['lang'])){
            
            $stmt = "SELECT LANG_".$lang[$_GET['lang']]." FROM LANG WHERE LANG_PT_BR=:texto";
            $row_name = "LANG_".$lang[$_GET['lang']];
            $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
    
        }else{
    
            $stmt = "SELECT LANG_PT_BR FROM LANG WHERE LANG_PT_BR=:texto";
            $row_name = "LANG_PT_BR";
            $lang = $_SESSION['lang'] = 'pt-br';
    
        }
    
        try {
            $sql=$conn->prepare($stmt);
            $sql->bindParam(':texto',$texto,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sql->execute();
            $row=$sql->fetch();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $texto = $texto;
        }
    
        if(isset($row[$row_name])){
            return $texto = $row[$row_name];
        }else{
            return $texto = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without knowing the database structure, its contents, its indexes, or the host it resides on, this will be rather difficult to answer properly …

Comment: When you ask a question about query optimization, you should run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` and include the result of that query in your question above. Please as text — not as a screenshot. It would also be helpful to run `EXPLAIN <query>` and include the result of that.

Comment: and you should check which is slow.if the sql execute direct in mysql slow.that maybe sql problem.if in execute in mysql not slow.than we can exam the php problem

Comment: add index LANG_PT_BR (if you have not yet done so) by executing `CREATE INDEX LANG_PT_BR ON LANG (LANG_PT_BR);`

Comment: How many rows in the table `LANG`?

Comment: Retrieving translations from DB, one sentence at a time, is unlikely to perform well. If you have e.g. 50 sentences to display that means 50 database round trips for every request. The localisation libraries I've used would load all translations at once and often use caches.

Comment: add index LANG_PT_BR (I had already done it)

Today I have this same code running via the cloud very well and without problems. On a local server, however, it is very slow, and a team responsible for the server complained exactly about the round trip to the database.

Comment: I believe it's a problem on the server, something in the configuration. But they insist on blaming the code. The table doesn't even have 500 rows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem is solved! As you already imagined, the problem was not in the code above, but in the settings in the PHP.INI of the local server. I used the Cloud settings and the speed was normalized.